# What is the impact on performance of the Monero network by using Kovri

Tags: monerod, blockchain, development, kovri

I understand that following implementation of Kovri there is a an affect on overall performance. Is anyone able to elaborate on this?

Comment: Considering Kovri as an abandoned project, I think we should consider to edit this question to "What is the impact on performance of the Monero network by using Dandelion++?"